# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory when calling GetAzureADAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext

Tags: c#, azure-functions, sharepoint-online

I'm using certificate to get ClientContext in function app(V1)
here is code:

```
ClientContext newClientContext;
            try
            {
                newClientContext = new AuthenticationManager().GetAzureADAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(SiteUrl, appId, tenant, certificate);
                newClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                return newClientContext;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                newClientContext = null;
                if (_logHelper != null)
                {
                    _logHelper.writeLog("GetAzureADContextError:"+ex.Message, TraceLevel.Error, ex);
                }
                return null;
            }
```

and my package is :
[image: package version list]

It works pretty well in local visual studio env,but get failed information after deploy to app services

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory, Version=2.29.0.1078, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: Upload the DLL files too.

Comment: I think your version is not compatible. You can download  `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` lower version as you are using V1. [Similar issue founded here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2373)

Comment: My project using version 3.14.2,do you mean I have to specify the version in config files?

Comment: I did not install this dll, it is depends on other nuget package.I mean Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication depends on Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory version 3.14 or above.I only install this nuget package.

Comment: I would suggest you to use [`Version="3.14.0"`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication/1.3.0) version it could resolved your issue.

Comment: Was the problem resolved?

Comment: That means you need to install it on azure.

Comment: what do you mean use Version 3.14.0?

Comment: I can not downgrade the dll cause some of my nuget packages depends on the high version of Version 3.14.

Comment: @KevinYANG Can you provide your .csproj file? That way it would be convenient for me to reproduce your error.

Comment: <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication" Version="1.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventGrid" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.26" />
    <PackageReference Include="SendGrid" Version="9.12.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="SharePointPnPCoreOnline" Version="2.24.1803" />
    <PackageReference Include="WindowsAzure.Storage" Version="8.7.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

Comment: @BowmanZhu  Is this enough for you ?

Comment: @KevinYANG OK, it should be enough. This piece of code is causing me a local problem and I am investigating the cause.

Comment: @BowmanZhu  The same dll will be the output file in bin folder, I mean it is already existed but different version.May be this method still use the old version in the program

Comment: https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Sites-Core/issues/1833  got very similar issue like this but not resolved

Comment: @KevinYANG After deploying to Azure using the package you provided, it seems to work normally. Your conjecture may be correct. I once encountered a similar problem when using the Storage package, and it was because of a version conflict. Can you fix this if you keep one package version?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209819/discussion-between-kevin-yang-and-bowmanzhu).

Comment: @BowmanZhu seems not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the error, the SDK [`SharePointPnPCoreOnline`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharePointPnPCoreOnline/2.24.1803) requests  `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory 2.29.0.1078`, but the sdk [`Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication/1.0.0-preview) needs `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` version higher than `3.14.2`. According to the situation, I suggest you use [key vault reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references) in your Azure Function. After we do that, we can remove sdk `Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication` and downgrade sdk `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` to version 2.29.

The detailed steps are as below.

1. [Configure MSI for Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet#add-a-system-assigned-identity)
2. Create an [access policy in Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-secure-your-key-vault#key-vault-access-policies) for the  Azure Function application identity
3. Get the certificate url

[image]
[image]

4. Save the url in the [Azure function Application settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings). Its formate should be like
   `@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=<your url>)`

[image]

5. Remove SDK `Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication` and downgrade sdk `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory`
6. Update code

```
 var s = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("cert");



            var cert = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(s),
                     (string)null,
                     X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
            try
            {
                using (var cc = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager().GetAzureADAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(
                        SiteUrl, appId, tenant,
                        cert))
                {
                    cc.Load(cc.Web, p => p.Title);
                    cc.ExecuteQuery();
                    log.Info("Via PnP, we have site: " + cc.Web.Title);
                };
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {



                log.Info(ex.Message);
            }
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I just thought about how to stop using this library.Unfortunately I can't see the picture because of network problems.In my method, I also use managed identity and give function app access policy to key vault already.

Comment: Hi @KevinYANG May I know what's the network problem ? Could you please provide more details ?

Comment: When I input the value to app settings,get error with InvalidSyntax

Comment: @KevinYANG Could you please provide a screenshot of the error INvalidSyntax ?

Comment: Sorry,solved.I'm now run the pipeline and have a try(using this kind of method to get the certificate)

Comment: @KevinYANG So could you please accept this solution as answer ?

Comment: Yes,of course.Cause I can not downgrade the library it is a good choice since I have to upgrade the run-time version of function app on azure.Thanks anyway!